# Solving the system $\sin2x \cos y=1$, $\cos2x \sin y=0$

Tags: trigonometry

I was solving a question and got stuck here. These are the equations I arrived at after solving the original question. These equations are correct.

> I need to find ordered pair of $x$ and $y$ where  $x$, $y$ are in $[0, \pi]$.
> $$\sin2x \cos y=1 \tag{1}$$
> $$\cos2x \sin y=0 \tag{2}$$
>
> How do I solve this?
>
> The answers are $(\frac{\pi}{4},0)$ and $(\frac{3\pi}{4},\pi)$.

I added them and used $\sin(A+B)$ but that did not give me definite values. A lot of values were satisfying this. SO should I just find all possible pairs (which would be a lot) and just substitute in each to check ?

Comment: There are not that many possible pairs as these conditions are quite restrictive. Remember that sines and cosines take values between -1 and 1, to effectively use the first condition.

Answer (score 1):

Note that, how $x$ and $y$ are in $[0,\pi]$, then $0\leq2x+y\leq3\pi$:
$$\sin(2x+y)=1, \implies 2x+y=\dfrac\pi2,\, \text{or}\,  2x+y=\dfrac{5\pi}{2}$$
And
$$\sin(y)\cos(2x)=0\implies \sin(y)=0, \,\text{or} \cos(2x)=0\implies y=0,\, \text{or}\, y=\pi, \, \text{or}\, x=\tfrac{\pi}{4}, \, \text{or}\, x=\tfrac{3\pi}{4}$$

Answer (score 0):

From the second equation we have that

- $\cos 2x=0\implies \sin 2x=1 \land \cos y=1$

that is $(\frac{\pi}{4},0)$.

Or

- $\sin y=0 \implies \cos y=\pm1$

and from the second equation

- $\cos y=1\implies \sin 2x=1$, that is $(\frac{\pi}{4},0)$
- $\cos y=-1\implies \sin 2x=-1$, that is $(\frac{3\pi}{4},\pi)$.

Answer (score 0):

We have $$\sin(2x+y)=1\implies 2x+y=2n\pi+\dfrac\pi2$$

$$\sin(2x-y)=1\implies 2x-y=2m\pi+\dfrac\pi2$$

$$2y=2\pi(n-m)\iff y=(n-m)\pi\equiv(n+m)\pi\pmod{2\pi}$$

$$4x=2\pi(n+m)+\pi\implies x=\dfrac{(n+m)\pi}2+\dfrac\pi4$$

Answer (score 0):

$$-1\le\sin\theta\le 1, -1\le\cos\gamma\le 1 \implies -1 \le \sin\theta\cos\gamma \le 1 \\ \implies \sin(2x)=\cos(y)\in \{-1,1\} \ (\because \sin(2x)\cos(y)=1)$$

Also, as you have done, $\textbf{sin(2x+y)=1}$. From the [general solutions for trigonometric functions](https://byjus.com/maths/trigonometric-equations/), we have the following cases,

> If $\sin(2x)=\cos(y)=1$, then $x=\dfrac{(4m+1)\pi}4$, $y=2l\pi$  and $2x+y=\dfrac{(4n+1)\pi}2$ (for the bold part) for some integers $m,l,n$. You can find a relation between $m,l,n$ by equating two expressions for $2x+y$.

> Try the same for $\sin(2x)=\cos(y)=-1$.